# Attempting to get columns to sit side by side CSS Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website on WordPress using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

I have a loop that goes through my case studies and prints them on the page into an 8 column wide space, I then attempt to put my sidebar next to these  case studies with a width of 4. However this just pushes my sidebar to the bottom of the page. The only solution I’ve found is to give it a negative margin-top, doing this then makes my background image different to the other pages so it can't be used.

Here is my code that generates the case studies and then generates my sidebar.

Thank you!

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="row case-study-block">
     <div id="page_content">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="case_summary_image col-md-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('casestudy img-responsive');?></a>
            </div>
                <div class="case_summary col-md-8"></a>
                    <a style="font-size:18px; line-height:30px; color:#666666; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- sidebar -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="row">
<div id="page_content">
<div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
<?php get_sidebar('case');?>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a `container` element wrapped around this?

Comment: Yes, its all in a container

Comment: Remove the div with clear. You're not trying to clear it. Also, are you trying to get your sidebar on the left or right side? Shouldn't your loop be inside the container rather than outside the container (might be repeating the container: col-md-8)

Comment: Is it just me who sees the same question over and over again. Do people read the docs these days?

Comment: @Christina It's really annoying..

Comment: @Sebsemillia - it is very annoying. I see a lot of redundant classes, unnecessary nested grids, and just horrible implementation (even in themes for sale, like double class tags called and closing img tag). They skipped a vital part of web dev, don't use a framework until you learn css and html and always RTFM.

Comment: @Christina hehe, true words spoken!! And the BT Manual is a very detailed and easy to read one (compared to some others frameworks/plugins)..

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like your html structure for bootstrap is wrong. Try this structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- WP post loop -->    
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php get_sidebar('case');?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you have the id `page_content` twice. ID's must be unique!

And if you want to nest `col-xx-xx` into other `col-xx-xx`'s (like you do in your case-study-block loop), you need to wrap the col's inside into a new `.row` first. Read more about it here: [**Bootstrap Nesting columns**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)